# Async request is not going to Firebase through action creators

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, firebase-authentication, redux-thunk

I am trying to create a LoginForm in which I am placing the the UI using react-native, but the backend logic is through redux framework. I have integrated with the firebase libraries and am trying to make an async call to the firebase using the action creators and reducers through redux-thunk.

App.js

```
.........
.........
render()
    {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
        return(
        <Provider store={ store } >
            <LoginForm />
        </Provider>
        );
    }
```

LoginForm.js

```
class LoginForm extends Component
{
.........
.........
onButtonPress () {
        const { email, password } = this.props;
        this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
    }

render()
    {
<CardSection>
                    <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} >
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </CardSection>
}
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email,
        password: state.auth.password
    };
};

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser })(LoginForm);
```

Actions
index.js

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
    console.log("Shikher1");
    return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password ).then( user => {
        dispatch ({ type: 'LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS' , payload: user });
    });
    };
};
```

Nothing is mentioned in the Reducer as such, I just wanted to make sure that the action gets triggered and the Async call is made. But nothing gets happened here. As I printed from the console.logs I can see that the callback function is getting executed and it calls the action creator too, but the firebase statement is not getting executed, as after its execution, it will return an object. Why is the firebase statement is not getting executed?

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in in your `LoginForm.js`, try to add these lines

```js
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email,
        password: state.auth.password
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    emailChanged: payload => dispatch(emailChanged(payload)),
    passwordChanged: payload => dispatch(passwordChanged(payload)),
    loginUser : payload => dispatch(loginUser (payload))
})

export default connect (mapStateToProps ,mapDispatchToProps )(LoginForm);
```

Comment: I added these lines in the code:
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email,
        password: state.auth.password
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    emailChanged: payload => dispatch(emailChanged(payload)),
    passwordChanged: payload => dispatch(passwordChanged(payload)),
    loginUser : payload => dispatch(loginUser (payload))
});

export default connect (mapDispatchToProps,mapStateToProps)(LoginForm);

I am getting error like:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined.

Comment: Oh sorry, try this 

```js 
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginForm)
```